# JPA overwrite record with auto_increment primary key

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've searched but nothing found for me. I have an entity class like this belove:

```
@Entity
public class Report {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "descrizione")
    private String descrizione = null;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }   
}
```

And a table into mysql db with auto_increment pk. But I don't know why the auto_increment works only when I start the web service. Later, hibernate just overwrite the last record without create a new one with the auto incremented primary key.

Into the application.properties I have this configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/civicsense?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=AAAAAAA
```

Some help will be appreciated

Comment: you should use GenerationType.AUTO instead of IDENTITY. also make sure you have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
for
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

and in the application.properties use:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Answer (score 0):

First, change your int to Long. And you can omit the strategy, since for MySQL `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is the same as `GenerationType.AUTO` which is equivalent to just add `@GeneratedValue`.

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

Also, your problem might be the way you are adding your entity. You might want to use `saveAndFlush()` in this case, since changes will be flushed to DB immediately in this command, which might be prevent your issue, because your actual method might not being committing on time.